# mvn release prepare fails when trying to commit tags

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin

When running mvn release:prepare I got this error:

```
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E155004: Run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
[ERROR] svn: E155004: Commit failed (details follow):
[ERROR] svn: E155004: Working copy 'trunk_svn' locked.
[ERROR] svn: E155004: 'trunk_svn' is already locked.
```

FYI : The tag doesn't exist in the remote repository.

Cheers

Comment: What have you tried? How are you regularly working with Subversion in your working area (command-line or e.g. TortoiseSVN)? What version of Subversion, etc.?

Comment: I'm using tortoiseSVN 1.8.1

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a discrepancy between Subversion versions, the one used by Maven and your TortoiseSVN. But I don't know enough about it to say for sure on basis of the information given.